# How to fix Facebook error "Platform Policy 8.2" in app with expo

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, expo

Received this alert from Facebook today:

> Your app doesn’t comply with the following:
>   **Platform Policy 8.2: Native iOS and Android apps that implement Facebook Login must use our official SDKs for Login. Please make sure
>   your Android app is using the most recent version of out SDK for
>   Login.**
>
> Specifically, it violates this policy:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/policy#7-2-photo (**Android apps
>   should use the default login behavior defined by the SDK, which may
>   use the web-view Login dialog. On iOS, only kiosk apps may use a
>   web-view Login dialog.**) Facebook requests to fix it in 6 days, in
>   other way the app will be subject to enforcement.

The issue is that we didn’t apply any changes to Facebook login on our own. The last thing that we did was updating expo version to “31.0.7", it went to Play Store on Jan, 15, 11:19. Before that we had version 30.

We need help with this. Could it be an Expo issue or something else?

Comment: _“The issue is that we didn’t apply any changes to Facebook login on our own.”_ - Facebook is enforcing its policies more forcefully these days, so it might simply be the case that you were in violation all the time, but they are only now taking notice and doing something about it.

Answer (score 0):

FB changes their policy quite frequently, when you don't follow their policy they can reject your app even you don't have any update recently.

It seems your apps doesn't use native facebook sdk to login. You have to follow their latest integration guide or users cannot login with facebook from your app anymore.